# How to force-restart OS X networking?

Tags: network, wifi

There's a coffee shop network I connect to fairly often.  Usually it works fine, but sometimes it gets into a state where the connection repeatedly fails about thirty seconds after connecting.  Once it gets into this state, nothing I can find will allow the connection to stay up short of rebooting my laptop completely.  This is extremely annoying.

To be specific, when I open the Network Diagnostics panel, I get green status lights on Wi-Fi, Wi-Fi Settings, and Network Settings, and red lights on ISP, Internet, and Server.  All of the below cause ISP/Internet/Server to briefly turn green, then fail again 15-30 seconds later.  If I'm quick, I *can* load a web page in the interval, so network connection is happening.

Things that don't work:

- Turn Wi-Fi Off/On from the menu bar
- `sudo ifconfig en0 down/up`
- kill mDNSResponder process
- waiting and hoping it will just fix itself

Thing that does work:

- Rebooting the computer

What else can I try?

(I am running El Cap 10.11.3 on a retina MacBook Pro.)

Comment: You can try clearing the DNS cache: "sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder" Note that it is different on earlier versions of macOS

Comment: I have this question too. Tired of restarting the whole computer. (The OP already said killing mDNSReponder was tried. Not working.) (Help!)

Comment: Same issue here. Ever fix this OP?

Answer (score 0):

The deepest reset I can think of would be to unload and reload the appropriate driver like:
`sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/<name_of_the_kext>.kext`
then reload it using
`sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/<name_of_the_kext>.kext`
However, I don't believe a kext file exists for the wifi hardware, and newer versions of macOS mostly did away with kext files.

One suggestion instead is to use a usb or thunderbolt wifi dongle instead.  You can always "power cycle" this by removing and re-inserting.